# How to call JSONObject in Retrofit api calls?

Tags: android, json

Example: My input is

```
        "items":[{
                "service_id":"1",
                "service_description":"description here",
                "service_quantity":1,
                "service_uom":"number",
                "service_price":"10000",
                "service_total":"10000",
                "service_taxid":1,
                "service_taxvalue":"10"
        },
        {
                "service_id":"2",
                "service_description":"description here",
                "service_quantity":1,
                "service_uom":"number",
                "service_price":"10000",
                "service_total":"10000",
                "service_taxid":1,
                "service_taxvalue":"10"
        }]
```

I declared like: API Call-

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("URL")
Observable<SampleResponse> generateInvoice(@Field("items") JSONArray params);
```

Declaration:

```
JSONObject service1 = new JSONObject();
try {
service1.put("service_id", id);
service1.put("service_description", Desc);
service1.put("service_quantity", Integer.valueOf(Qty));
service1.put("service_uom", "number");
service1.put("service_price", Amt);
service1.put("service_total", GAmt);
service1.put("service_taxid", 1);
service1.put("service_taxvalue", 5);
Log.d("jsonobject created",""+service1);
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


JSONArray array = new JSONArray().put(service1);
presenter.generateInvoice(array);
```

> Error at backend: '{\"service_id\":3,\"service_description\":\"Mobile
>   Application\",\"service_quantity\":5,\"service_uom\":\"number\",\"service_price\":\"650\",\"service_total\":\"3640\",\"service_taxid\":1,\"service_taxvalue\":5}';

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 pojo class based on your request.

```
class RequestClass {
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    var items: List<Item> = arrayListOf()
}
```

**Item** class will contains all the string fields that you have in your request, and in retrofit api you need to pass **RequestClass** like below. and remove the **@FormUrlEncoded**

```
@POST("URL")
Observable<SampleResponse> generateInvoice(@Body RequestClass requestClass);
```